# split full email addresses into name and email?

Tags: php, email-validation

There seems to be many acceptable email address formats in the To: and From: raw email headers ...

```
person@place.com
person <person@place.com>
person
Another Person <person@place.com>
'Another Person' <person@place.com>
"Another Person" <person@place.com>
```

After not finding any effective PHP functions for splitting out names and addresses, I've written the following code.

You can **[DEMO IT ON CODEPAD](http://codepad.org/Aao5phc2)** to see the output...

```
// validate email address
function validate_email( $email ){
    return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? true : false;
}

// split email into name / address
function email_split( $str ){
    $name = $email = '';
    if (substr($str,0,1)=='<') {
        // first character = <
        $email = str_replace( array('<','>'), '', $str );
    } else if (strpos($str,' <') !== false) {
        // possibly = name <email>
        list($name,$email) = explode(' <',$str);
        $email = str_replace('>','',$email);
        if (!validate_email($email)) $email = '';
        $name = str_replace(array('"',"'"),'',$name);
    } else if (validate_email($str)) {
        // just the email
        $email = $str;
    } else {
        // unknown
        $name = $str;
    }
    return array( 'name'=>trim($name), 'email'=>trim($email) );
}

// test it
$tests = array(
    'person@place.com',
    'monarch <themonarch@tgoci.com>',
    'blahblah',
    "'doc venture' <doc@venture.com>"
    );

foreach ($tests as $test){
    echo print_r( email_split($test), true );
}
```

Am I missing anything here? Can anyone recommend a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to make one regex to your test cases:

```
person@place.com
person <person@place.com>
person
Another Person <person@place.com>
'Another Person' <person@place.com>
"Another Person" <person@place.com>
```

using `preg_match` with this regex will surely help you bit.

```
function email_split( $str ){
$sPattern = "/([\w\s\'\"]+[\s]+)?(<)?(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))?(>)?/g";
preg_match($sPattern,$str,$aMatch);

if(isset($aMatch[1]))
{
echo $aMatch[1] //this is name;
}

if(isset($aMatch[3]))
{
echo $aMatch[3] //this is EmailAddress;
}
}
```

Note: I just noticed that single "person" i.e. your third test case could be discarded with this regex (just that because of space constraint in regex) so,at first line of your `email_split` function, append space at last place of your string.

Then it would be bang on target.

Thanks, Hope this helps.

Code I tried:

```
<?php

// validate email address
function validate_email($email) {
   return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? true : false;
}

// split email into name / address
function email_split($str) {
   $str .=" ";
   $sPattern = '/([\w\s\'\"]+[\s]+)?(<)?(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))?(>)?/';
   preg_match($sPattern, $str, $aMatch);
   //echo "string";
   //print_r($aMatch);
   $name = (isset($aMatch[1])) ? $aMatch[1] : '';
   $email = (isset($aMatch[3])) ? $aMatch[3] : '';
   return array('name' => trim($name), 'email' => trim($email));
}

// test it
$tests = array(
   'person@place.com',
   'monarch <themonarch@tgoci.com>',
   'blahblah',
   "'doc venture' <doc@venture.com>"
);

foreach ($tests as $test) {
   echo "<pre>";
   echo print_r(email_split($test), true);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```

Output I got:

```
Array
(
   [name] => 
   [email] => person@place.com
)

Array
(
   [name] => monarch
   [email] => themonarch@tgoci.com
)

Array
(
   [name] => blahblah
   [email] => 
)

Array
(
   [name] => 'doc venture'
   [email] => doc@venture.com
)
```

Comment: This looks amazing! I've tried it on codepad ... http://codepad.org/TZUBdGjQ ... but am getting the error "Unknown modifier 'g'". Suggestions?

Comment: I have tried this in my machine test environment (PHP version 5.4.3) for code I have used and output I got -> check the edit.

Comment: Happy that I could provide a solution :)

Comment: Cool and precise script for the agenda. Thanks for that. I have a scenario in that name part contains '-' hyphen symbol in it. then the script only returns the first portion of the name and email portion as email. test full email as (INFO - JOSAN <info@mydomain.com>)

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
function email_split($str) {
    $parts = explode(' ', trim($str));
    $email = trim(array_pop($parts), "<> \t\n\r\0\x0B");
    $name = trim(implode(' ', $parts), "\"\' \t\n\r\0\x0B");
    if ($name == "" && strpos($email, "@") === false) {             // only single string - did not contain '@'
        $name = $email;
        $email = "";
    }
    return array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email);
}
```

Looks like this is about twice as fast as the regex solution.

Note: the OPs third test case (for my purposes) is not needed.  But in the interest of answering the OP I added the if stmt to produce the OPs expected results.  This could have been done other ways (check the last element of $parts for '@').

Answer (score 0):

use preg_match in php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

or in my opinion, you can make your own function (let say **get_email_address**), it catch **@** character and then get the 'rest-left-string' from **@** until '<' character and 'rest-right-string' from **@** until '>' character.

for example, string `monarch <themonarch@tgoci.com>` will return 'rest-left-string' = `themonarch` and 'rest-right-string' = `tgoci.com` . finally, your function **get_email_address** will return **themonarch@tgoci.com**

hopefully it help.. :)

Comment: There are enough conditions and exceptions that no single `preg_match` seems to do the trick :( Can you imagine a working regex for the job that includes validation?

Comment: yes, i see, i can imagine it after look at the content of your $tests variable :D. how about my second opinion above?

Comment: this isn't about splitting `john@doe.com` into `john` and `doe.com` ... this is about extracting full name and full email address from headers.

Comment: oo.. sorry about that :(. just explore the first one : preg_match :)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the regex fails in a couple of conditions of the fullname:

- non alphanumeric chars (eg. "Amazon.it")
- non printable chars
- emojs

i adjusted the expression this way

```php
$sPattern = '/([^<]*)?(<)?(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))?(>)?/';
```

and now all chars are correctly recognized and splitted.

tested with

```html
$address = "Test User @ `` . !!  <test@email.com";
```

after 7 years, hope this helps :)